# Can we find sufficient conditions in which this equation have only three distinct real roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let us consider the polynomial equation:

$$ξ₁x⁸+ξ₂x⁷+ξ₃ x⁶+ξ₄  x⁵+ξ₅ x⁴+ξ₆  x³+ξ₇  x²+(ξ₈-1)  x+ξ₉ =0$$

where $ξ_{i}$ are real coefficients.

My **question** is: Can we find sufficient conditions in which this equation have only three distinct real roots.

Comment: Obviously not. If $f(z)$ is a polynomial of $n$ degree then there are $n$ distinct zeros of the polynomial. To clarify, are you asking if there is a condition in which there are 3 real roots and 5 complex roots?

Comment: @Aleksandar: Yes.

Comment: Okay, makes complete sense.

Comment: You can rewrite all of this equivalently asking if there are sufficient conditions on the coefficients of a real polynomial of degree $8$ such that it has exactly $3$ distinct real roots.

Comment: It is impossible to have 3 real roots and 5 complex roots, since complex roots of a real polynomials come in pair. you need at least one real double root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Since a polynomial of the form:

$p(z)=\sum_{k=0}^m a_{k}z^{k}$

Can be expressed as the following where $\beta_{1},...,\beta_{m}$ are $m$ roots of the polynomial:

$p(z)=a_{0}(z-\beta_{1})...(z-\beta_{m})$

Assume $5$ of the $8$ roots are complex and expand the polynomial. See if there exist conditions in which there could be 3 real and 5 complex roots.

I.e.

$\xi_{1}(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-(\alpha_{1}+i\beta_{1})(x-(\alpha_{2}+i\beta_{2}))...(x-(\alpha_{5}+i\beta_{5}))$

Expand this out and see if there exist conditions in which this could be a polynomial with real coefficients.